# How to load a sparse matrix efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

Given a file with this structure:

- Single column lines are keys
- Non-zero values of the keys

For example:

```
abc
ef 0.85
kl 0.21
xyz 0.923
cldex 
plax 0.123
lion -0.831
```

**How to create a sparse matrix, `csr_matrix`?**

```
('abc', 'ef') 0.85
('abc', 'kl') 0.21
('abc', 'xyz') 0.923
('cldex', 'plax') 0.123
('cldex', 'lion') -0.31
```

I've tried:

```
from collections import defaultdict

x = """abc
ef  0.85
kl  0.21
xyz 0.923
cldex 
plax    0.123
lion    -0.831""".split('\n')

k1 = ''
arr = defaultdict(dict)
for line in x:
    line = line.strip().split('\t')
    if len(line) == 1:
        k1 = line[0]
    else:
        k2, v = line
        v = float(v)
        arr[k1][k2] = v
```

[out]

```
>>> arr
defaultdict(dict,
            {'abc': {'ef': 0.85, 'kl': 0.21, 'xyz': 0.923},
             'cldex': {'plax': 0.123, 'lion': -0.831}})
```

Having the nested dict structure isn't as convenient as the `scipy` sparse matrix structure.

**Is there a way to read the file in the given format above easily into any of the `scipy` sparse matrix object?**

Comment: Scipy sparse matrices, all formats, have simple numeric indices.  So the first step is to map the strings on to unique numbers, e.g. 'abc' => 0, 'cldex'=>1, 'ef'=>0, etc.  Then create the `coo` style of inputs - `data`, `row`, `col`.

Answer (score 5):

Converting @hpaulj's comment into answer, you can iteratively add to lists of row and column indices. Later, factorise these using `pd.factorize`, `np.unique`, or `sklearn`'s `LabelEncoder`, and convert to a sparse `coo_matrix`.

```
from scipy import sparse
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

rows, cols, values = [], [], []
for line in x.splitlines():
   if ' ' not in line.strip():
       ridx = line
   else:
       cidx, value = line.strip().split()       
       rows.append(ridx)
       cols.append(cidx)
       values.append(value)

rows, rinv = pd.factorize(rows)
cols, cinv = pd.factorize(cols)

sp = sparse.coo_matrix((values, (rows, cols)), dtype=np.float32)
# sp = sparse.csr_matrix((np.array(values, dtype=np.float), (rows, cols)))
```

```
sp.toarray()
array([[ 0.85 ,  0.21 ,  0.923,  0.   ,  0.   ],
       [ 0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.123, -0.831]], dtype=float32)
```

If required, you can use `rinv` and `cinv` to perform an inverse mapping (convert indices to strings).

Answer (score 1):

Currently, in version 0.23, pandas have implemented sparse versions of Series and Data-Frames. Coincidentally your data can be seen as a Series with multi-level index, so you could exploit this fact to build the sparse matrix. In addition, if consistent, your format can be read using a few lines of pandas, for example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

lines = StringIO("""abc
ef  0.85
kl  0.21
xyz 0.923
cldex
plax    0.123
lion    -0.831""")

# load Series
s = pd.read_csv(lines, delim_whitespace=True, header=None, names=['k', 'v'])
s = s.assign(k2=pd.Series(np.where(np.isnan(s.v), s.k, np.nan)).ffill())
result = s[~np.isnan(s.v)].set_index(['k2', 'k']).squeeze()

# convert to sparse matrix (csr)
ss = result.to_sparse()
coo, rows, columns = ss.to_coo(row_levels=['k'], column_levels=['k2'], sort_labels=True)
print(coo.tocsr())
```

**Output**

```
  (0, 0)    0.85
  (1, 0)    0.21
  (2, 1)    -0.831
  (3, 1)    0.12300000000000001
  (4, 0)    0.9229999999999999
```

The [to_coo](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.SparseSeries.to_coo.html) method not only returns the matrix, but also the columns and row labels, hence doing also the inverse mapping. In the above example returns the following:

```
['ef', 'kl', 'lion', 'plax', 'xyz']
['abc', 'cldex']
```

Where `'ef'` corresponds to index `0` of the rows and `'abc'` corresponds to index `0` of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have the dict

```
dox = {'abc': {'ef': 0.85, 'kl': 0.21, 'xyz': 0.923},'cldex': {'plax': 0.123, 'lion': -0.831}}
```

this should help you take it to a sparsematrix:

```
indptr = [0]
indices = []
data = []
vocabulary = {}

for d in dox:
     for term in dox[d]:
         index = vocabulary.setdefault(term, len(vocabulary))
         indices.append(index)
         data.append(dox[d][term])
         indptr.append(len(indices))

mat = csr_matrix((data, indices, indptr), dtype=float)
```

This utilizes scipy's [example](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html) for an incremental matrix build. Here is the output:

```
mat.todense()
```

[image]